# error #1215 creating foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

---

```
create table LOCATION ( 
warehouseID varchar(3), 
locationID varchar(3), 
aisle int, shelf int, 
bin int, 
capacity double, 
primary key(warehouseID,locationID), 
foreign key(warehouseID) references WAREHOUSE(warehouseID) )
```

---

```
create table PROD_LOCATION ( 
warehouseID varchar(3), 
locationID varchar(3), 
productNum int, 
quantityOnHand int, 
primary key(warehouseID,locationID,productNum), 
foreign key(warehouseID) references WAREHOUSE(warehouseID),
foreign key(locationID) references LOCATION(locationID),
foreign key(productNum) references PRODUCT(productNum) )
```

---

```
create table PICKING_LIST ( 
warehouseID varchar(3), 
locationID varchar(3), 
productNum int, 
requestNum int, 
quantityPicked int, 
datePicked date, 
pickerStaffID int, 
primary key(warehouseID,locationID,productNum,requestNum), 
foreign key(warehouseID) references WAREHOUSE(warehouseID), 
foreign key(locationID) references LOCATION(locationID),
foreign key(productNum) references PRODUCT(productNum), 
foreign key(requestNum) references STOCK_REQUEST(requestNum), 
foreign key(pickerStaffID) references EMPLOYEE(staffID) )
```

keeps coming up with error #1215, but if i remove the lines about creating a foreign key to the LOCATION table the code works.

Comment: Do u have a table WAREHOUSE ? and if yes how does it look like ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have a table defined as `WAREHOUSE`, I think the problem is 
data type mismatch between `WAREHOUSE(warehouseID)` and `LOCATION(warehouseID)`

Most probably, you have defined WAREHOUSE table as (a sample)

```
create table WAREHOUSE(warehouseID int not null primary key);
```

In your LOCATION table `warehouseID` is of  `varchar(3)`

Make sure, in both tables referencing column(s) has same data type

If I change your table structure a little, it works fine

```
create table LOCATION ( 
warehouseID int,
fk_warehouseid int, 
locationID varchar(3), 
aisle int, shelf int, 
bin int, 
capacity double, 
primary key(warehouseID,locationID), 
foreign key(warehouseID) references WAREHOUSE(warehouseID) );
```

Answer (score 0):

LOCATION table has a composite primary key, so your foreign key reference to LOCATION table should have both the columns in the primary key. you have only defined only with the locationID. Can you uniquely identify the location table with only the locationID, then change the primary key.

Otherwise, change the foreignkey reference to include the warehouseID also and you will be fine.